# Calculate LIKE FOR LIKE measure on date hierarchy with filter for each member of another hierarchy

Tags: ssas, mdx, olap

So what I am trying to achieve is:

- calculate TTV for each week of year,
- calculate TTV only for members of another hierarchy that had TTV value for same week in previous year (or neighbouring weeks),

So my current query should display TTV for each member of date hierarchy if there was TTV in parallel period (previous year). But I want it to be calculated for each member of Sales Group hierarchy separately - otherwise the result would be wrong, as there always is SOME TTV of SOME  Groups - but I want to take into account that SOME Groups didn't have TTV in previous year, so their results should be excluded from TTV for the current year.

The code goes like this:

```
CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].[TTV -1 R/RL4L]
 AS IIF((
 ISEMPTY((ParallelPeriod(
                    [Data Raportu].[Data raportu RTD].[Rok],
                    1,
                    [Data Raportu].[Data raportu RTD].CurrentMember
    ),
        [Measures].[TTV])
        ) is false

        OR

        ISEMPTY((ParallelPeriod(
                    [Data Raportu].[Data raportu RTD].[Rok],
                    1,
                    [Data Raportu].[Data raportu RTD].PrevMember
    ),
        [Measures].[TTV])
        ) is false

        OR

        ISEMPTY((ParallelPeriod(
                    [Data Raportu].[Data raportu RTD].[Rok],
                    1,
                    [Data Raportu].[Data raportu RTD].NextMember
    ),
        [Measures].[TTV])
        ) is false
        ) is false


, [Measures].[TTV] , NULL)
        
        * 
        
        {[Sales Group].[Sub-channel].[Channel].[Group]}, 
VISIBLE = 1 ,  ASSOCIATED_MEASURE_GROUP = 'PBI'  ;
```

Translating - if I get it right - into: IF there was TTV one year ago for: current member OR prev member OR next member (may it be day or week, as [Data Raportu RTD] hierarchy consists of YEAR-WEEK-DAY) display the current TTV.

But I don't know how to get the second part - narrow the TTV to each member that had TTV in previous periods.